# Greatest number of edges in a graph not containing a hamilton path

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Inspired by the question, where the greatest number of edges in a hamiltonian
 graph was asked, I have a similar question, but for hamilton paths.

- How many edges can a simple undirected graph contain, if it has no hamilton
  path ?

  It is clear that a graph can have $\binom {n-1}{2}$ edges without having a hamilton
  path (just take the complete graph with $n-1$ vertices and an isolated vertex).
  But does a graph with $\binom {n-1}{2}+1$ edges necessarily have a hamilton path ?

  What if the graph has to be connected ? What is the maximum number
  of edges in this case ?

Comment: Related to OP's question: are there any known thresholds in random graphs ([similar to these thresholds for giant components and connectivity in the Erdős-Rényi model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G.28n.2C_p.29)) for existence of a Hamilton path/circuit?

Comment: Every graph with at least $\binom{n-1}{2}+2$ edges has a Hamilton cycle. Deleting a single edge in such a graph still leaves you with a Hamilton path, so every graph with at least $\binom{n-1}{2}+1$ edges has a Hamilton path.

Comment: @ross So simple, but I did not get it, thanks!